# Shortest proof for showing $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}{2}]$ is a PID.

Tags: abstract-algebra, alternative-proof, principal-ideal-domains

I'm looking for an easy proof for that $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}{2}]$ is a PID.

One proof I know is to show that the field norm is a Dedekind-Hasse norm, but this proof is quite dirty( that it proves case by case) and technical.

Since any ring is a PID iff it admits a Dedekind-Hasse norm, I think every proof would look similar to the one I know. However, since this problem has been on qualifying exam quite several times , I'm curious if there is one which is less technical. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is, by the way, a standard example of a P.I.D. that is *not* a Euclidean domain.

Comment: @Travis Yes I know that, but proving that it is not ED using universal divisor is quite straightforward.

Comment: The method I know is to use the fact that this is the ring of integers of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-19})$. The Minkowski bound is 25, which reduces this to a finite, fiddly computation. This is relatively high powered.

Comment: What is «Q.E.»?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Qualifying Exam

Comment: @Rubertos, when you use an abbreviation please explain what it means the first time you use it. If you only use it once, then don't use it.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Edited :)